# Trigger.IO Is it possible to lock certain views' screen orientation?

Tags: android, ios, screen-orientation, trigger.io

Is it possible to programmatically set the orientation of a single view to only portrait or landscape while maintaining freedom on other views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Our display module has a JavaScript API to force a particular orientation and then release it to all any:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/display.html#api

Answer (score 0):

yes, the parent view controller is the limiting factor. You cannot easily rotate to landscape when the parent prohibits this. But when the parent allows e.g portrait and landscape then the next viewcontroller called by the navigation controller can limit to e.g portrait only.
the other way is difficult: if the parent limits to portrait then apple standard technic would not allow the view cobtroller to rotate to landscape.